# my controller function is able to handle the OPTIONS request sent by Postman, but it cannot handle the OPTIONS request sent by the browser

Tags: spring-boot, cors, postman, preflight

Firstly, here is my merge controller function.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/merge",method = {RequestMethod.GET,
            RequestMethod.POST,
            RequestMethod.PUT,
            RequestMethod.DELETE,
            RequestMethod.OPTIONS})
public String merge(@RequestBody FileEntity fileEntity, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        System.out.println("merge-method-name"+request.getMethod());
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        return "access OK";

    }
```

When I send an OPTIONS request to this controller function using Postman, the function can run properly.

[postman view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogVa2.png)

However, when I send a POST request to this endpoint using a browser (which first sends an OPTIONS request followed by the actual POST request), my merge function does not respond to the initial OPTIONS request.

[browser view1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuHyW.png)

[browser view2 -- response detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kTjz.png)

I have read the article 【 [spring-cors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc-cors.html)】 and understand that configuring CORS in Spring Boot is necessary to solve the cross-origin issue. This leads to my first question: Why is the OPTIONS request from Postman correctly handled by the merge function, while the OPTIONS request sent by the browser cannot be handled correctly?

I tried adding annotations @CrossOrigin, which can solve my problem, but they cannot address my previous question.

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/merge",method = {RequestMethod.GET,
                RequestMethod.POST,
                RequestMethod.PUT,
                RequestMethod.DELETE,
                RequestMethod.OPTIONS})
        @CrossOrigin(origins = "*",
                methods = {RequestMethod.GET,
                        RequestMethod.POST,
                        RequestMethod.PUT,
                        RequestMethod.DELETE,
                        RequestMethod.OPTIONS})
        public String merge(@RequestBody FileEntity fileEntity, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
            System.out.println("merge-method-name"+request.getMethod());
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return "access OK";

        }
```

This is the code for my only filter, which mainly validates the correctness of the JWT:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest re = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String requestURI = re.getRequestURI();
        if (requestURI.contains("/login")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            System.out.println(((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI());
            System.out.println(((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod());
            String token = re.getParameter("JWT");
            try {
                JWTUtils.verify(token);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("=========token  fail。");
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("=========token success。");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

This is my JavaScript code, in case it helps you

[My Js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Ztf.png)

Finally, I would like to remind everyone not to forget my question: Why is the OPTIONS request from Postman correctly handled by the merge function, while the OPTIONS request sent by the browser cannot be handled correctly?

Thank You。